# Windows server 2008 task scheduler does not run task at start up

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have VPS with Windows Server 2008. I have configured Task Scheduler to run the *.exe (please, see below XML file I retrieved from `c:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Chronos\`). The `Run on startup` trigger is enabled (I suppose it is `BootTrigger`).

The task runs and works until the Windows reboots due to updates or other reasons. The task is not started after reboot. I must login to Windows and manually start Task Scheduler, select the task and press `Run` button). Why it does not launch the task on Windows startup?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-09-06T16:47:00.9812</Date>
    <Author>VMI28078\Administrator</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
      <UserId>VMI28078\chronos</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>999</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>D:\chronos\gate\ChronosGate.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>rVPSgate.config</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>D:\chronos\gate</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: @downvoter: please, explain why?

Answer (score -1):

The Web has many advices on using INSTSRV or SC but:

- INSTSRV.EXE is NOT present in Windows Server 2008 R2
- SC.EXE did not help since it does not allow to create services using *.bat files (I need to pass command line argument to my *.exe which could be accomplished using a *.bat file)
- cron for windows - maybe yes, I did not try

The easiest way is to use http://nssm.cc which has GUI and worked like a charm for me.